# How do I create an Excel query to return a sub table from a larger table where values from two columns must match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

to clarify, i have an excel spread sheet 3 columns: `NAME` `AVAILABLE STOCK` and `REQUIRED AMOUNT`

I would like to compare cells in each row between columns `AVAILABLE STOCK` and `REQUIRED AMOUNT`

If the values are not the same, omit that row, if the values are the same then return that row. This can be achieved in PostgreSQL very easily, but I am not sure how to approach this in Excel.

So once more to clarify, I am looking for a query where only the rows where the last two columns have same cell values are to be returned. Thank you!

I am not looking to create some 4th row, I would like to return a subtable of the 3 rows, just only with the filtered values

Comment: When you say `query`, are you wanting to do something in power query? This seems easily solvable without power query, where you simply have another column with the formula `=a2=b2`. This will return a true or false, and you can then filter your table on TRUE.

Comment: I hadn't considered filtering based on a TRUE column, but I would very much still like to understand how to achieve the same using power query given I will have to use it eventually :()

Comment: This is insanely easy if you have Excel  O365 or Excel 2021.  What version are you using?

Comment: @MaxR I am using Excel 2019, to reiterate I am trying to make a query that will return the table with all columns, but only the rows where the last two cells match (since I have 3 columns)

Comment: add a helper column with a formula to compare the columns and then create a new table with an autofilter.
Otherwise it is easy to do in Power Query.